# body-parser(node.js) not able to understand form POST using fetch browser api

Tags: javascript, node.js, form-data, fetch-api

on sending form data using fetch api  as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' from browser to nodejs server, body-parser at node.js server not showing data sent but some object that is not understandable.

Here is the html form code:

```
<body>
<form action="#" id="formToSubmit">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="xyz">
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="7777777777">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="submitForm()">
</form>

<script>
    function submitForm(){
        var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("formToSubmit"));
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/ppum", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'                 
            },
            body: form // problem is here
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));

    }
</script>
```

Here is the node server code for body parser:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Here is the output of "req.body" at server:

```
{"------WebKitFormBoundary5jfSRwRQ4GjgeApo\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name":"\"name\"\r\n\r\nxyz\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary5jfSRwRQ4GjgeApo\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"phone\"\r\n\r\n7777777777\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary5jfSRwRQ4GjgeApo--\r\n"}
```

problem is how to send data as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' from client side.

why is the output like as shown and how to correct  it.

Note:was previously using [stackoverflow.com/a/37562814/3690154](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37562814/3690154) and it workes. if you have some suggesting on how to convert FormData to something like in this answer that will be highly appreciated

Comment: well i guess it is url encoded?

Comment: @philipp — It really, really, isn't.

Comment: but it should be ;)

Comment: @philipp body-parser is able to understand body like 'lorem=ipsum&name=binny' but not using FormData().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we are rebuilding formBody from [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object:

```
<body>
<form action="#" id="formToSubmit">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="xyz">
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="7777777777">
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="submitForm()">
</form>

<script>
    function submitForm(){
        var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("formToSubmit"));
        var formBody = [];
        for ( var key of form.keys()){
            var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key);
            var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(form.get(key));
            formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
        }
        formBody = formBody.join("&");
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/ppum", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'                 
            },
            body: formBody
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));

    }
</script>
```

Now body-parser is able to parse it correctly:

```
{"name":"xyz","phone":"7777777777"}
```

Also changed the type of submit button from 'submit' to 'button' as per Quentin suggested.

Note: You can also apply this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562814/3690154

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems.

## Including your form data

> ```
> new FormData("formToSubmit");
> ```

The argument you pass here needs to be **a form**. You are passing it a **string**.

```
new FormData(document.getElementById("formToSubmit"));
```

## Content Type

Setting the `Content-Type` header manually won't cause `fetch` to encode the content in that format.

You are passing a `FormData` object, so the content will be encoded as a multipart request.

You need to use a body parser that can handle that format. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076807/node-expressjs-parsing-a-multipart-form-data-post-data-using-body-parser-middl) for the details of how to do that.

## Submit buttons

Submit buttons submit forms.

You need to prevent the browser from leaving the page after starting the ajax request.

Using the 1990s style event binding you are using, you need to change:

> ```
> onClick="submitForm()"
> ```

to

```
onclick="submitForm(); return false;"
```

You should switch to a [modern method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) though.

Comment: was previously using https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562814/3690154 and it workes. if you have some suggesting on how to convert FormData to something like in this answer that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: this thing onclick="submitForm(); return false;" just owns me. Heads off buddy.